# NTP - fix massive offset

Tags: linux, ntp, rhel-5, ntpdate, ntpd

I've got a RHEL 5.4 and I'm synced to my NTP server .... I have managed to reduce the jitter to almost 0 with

```
ntpq -q
```

But then it came right back. The huge offset remains regardless of what I do. I also tried

```
[root@myHostname ~]# tinker panic 0
-bash: tinker: command not found
```

I can't find much else on the internet besides the "-q" command because it seems to work for everyone.

this is how bad it is currently:

```
[root@chtlcprvc1 ~]# ntpq -p
remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
=========================================================================
+timeServer1 192.5.41.209     2 u   57   64  377   14.077  -548695 160.627
-timeServer2 128.252.19.1     2 u   38   64  377   14.090  -548714 103.667
*timeServer3 128.252.19.1     2 u   57   64  377    0.295  -548695 158.982
-timeServer4 192.5.41.209     2 u   24   64  377    0.351  -548722 161.058
-timeServer5 128.252.19.1     2 u   59   64  377   54.080  -548712 105.954
+timeServer6 128.252.19.1     2 u  114   64  366   57.711  -548689 166.360
```

Not sure if you need more information. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

It was a Xen VM and I had to use set this in /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
xen.independent_wallclock=1
```

then bounce network ... after that I set the time manually with:

```
date--set="JAN 11 2016 18:00:00"
```

then ran

```
service ntpd stop
ntpd -gq
service ntpd start
```